# How to separate Rails Rspec tests that make api calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec

I am writing rspec features tests that make live api calls. I want the capacity to run all non-api tests with the simple command rspec, and then some way to call the live api tests separately. Perhaps there is a way to use ARGV or to exclude some tests from the general rspec namespace and still have full features test capabilities. Any thoughts?

Comment: why don,t you use vcr gem for recording of api response . so it will not need to HIT api again and again

Comment: I thought about that, but I actually want to periodically test the live api to make sure their methods haven't changed as well as if my code is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tag your API specs, take a look at the RSpec documentation: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option

If you want to use environment variables for filtering:

`spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding api: true unless ENV['ALL']
end
```

With this setup `rspec spec` command will filter out all the specs marked as `api`.

If you want to run whole suite including API specs `ALL=true rspec spec`.

Comment: Great Solution! I can confirm that this sweet little method works perfectly. Thank you Mikhail.